# How to use the reference component in AEM Template

Tags: aem, aem-6

am having a requirement to use a common content in all the pages. So I decided to use the reference component in AEM. I have created a new page and authored the content. How can this content can be used in the templates, so that it will appear in all pages without re-authoring.

Comment: Since you are using AEM 6 with jsp - which is not the preferred combination I would say: Are you working with the Classic UI or with the Touch UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using AEM 6 version, you can utilize the concept of design dialogs in components in static templates. You create a component, add design dialog and choose the fields in the design dialog, which once is authored will reflect in all pages created with that template.

The only activity you have to do while authoring is, you need to add and author the component in a page created with specific template.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the AEM 6.3 or more, Experience Fragments can be used, you can configure the experience fragment in the template and can be seen across all the pages.

You can use the experience fragment in individual pages as well.

> https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-learn/sites/experience-fragments/experience-fragments-feature-video-use.html

Comment: Am using AEM6 , is there any way I can achieve. The base template is in JSP.

Comment: There should not be a problem even though you use JSP, this is an old video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UztlIocv80) might help you. It's a component where you drag on to the page and select the required component. You can also use Content fragments which are similar to reference components. Its evolving from recent past from reference component to content fragments and to experience fragments